# Making a (bad) custom sqrt symbol

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts, sqrt

For puerile personal amusement, I'd like to make a replacement `\sqrt` macro that typesets the radical/surd symbols appallingly, to match a plotting package with... interesting aesthetics:

[image: Bad root]

Is it possible to do this sort of override in pure TeX (possibly including TikZ), without needing to make alternative math-font glyphs? Ideally able to work for the usual range of content sizes, and hints for also messing up the `\hat` would be much appreciated!

Comment: yes just draw individual rules as separate paths so you do not get mitred corners you could use picture mode for really oure tex with no back-end specific specials or tikz or pstricks etc to give a wider choice of line widths and slopes using pdf or postscript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No Tikz (or any driver specific `\special`s) required:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(100,100)
  
\thicklines
\put(40,50){\line(-1,6){3}}
\thinlines
\put(40,50){\line(1,6){5}}
\put(45,80){\line(1,0){25}}
\put(57,77){\line(1,-1){10}}
\put(57,77){\line(-1,-1){10}}
\put(50,50){\Huge\textsf{X}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can this be adapted for use inline in equations, with autosizing according to the argument and local font size? (I will try, but very inexpert in this corner of TeX... any pointers very welcome. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David for his answer. Avoiding dependencies would have been nice, but in the end I went with a TikZ version, to use its relative positioning, automatic modes, etc. Improvements welcome.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\badsqrt}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{%
    \node(x){\ensuremath{#1}};

    \coordinate[above left= 0.8ex and 0.01ex of x.west] (a);
    \coordinate[below right= 0.1ex and 0.3ex of x.base west] (b);
    \coordinate[left= 0.03ex of b] (b2);
    \coordinate[below right= 0.1ex and 0.45ex of x.north west] (c);
    \coordinate[above right= 0.02ex and 0.05ex of c] (c2);
    \coordinate[below left= 0.1ex and 0.4ex of x.north east] (d);

    \draw[-, thick] (a)--(b);
    \draw[-] (b2)--(c2);
    \draw[-] (c)--(d);
  }}

\newlength{\badhatxw}
\newcommand{\badhat}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{%
    \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (x){\ensuremath{#1}};
    \settowidth{\badhatxw}{\ensuremath{#1}}

    \coordinate[below left= 0.01ex and 0.5\badhatxw of x.north] (l);
    \coordinate[below right= 0.03ex and 0.52\badhatxw of x.north] (r);
    \coordinate[above right= 0.6ex and 0.02ex of x.north] (c1);
    \coordinate[above left= 0.59ex and 0.03ex of x.north] (c2);

    \draw[-, inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (l)--(c1);
    \draw[-, inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (r)--(c2);
  }}


\begin{document}

 \section*{Check this out: \protect\badsqrt{x}}

 How do \badsqrt{x}, \badsqrt{X}, \badsqrt{\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x},\\
 {\Huge \badsqrt{x}}, {\Huge \badsqrt{\badhat{x}}}, and \badsqrt{\badhat{x}} look?

\end{document}
```

[image: Bad sqrt and hat examples]